# Slack interactive buttons not working getting error: missing_subtype

Tags: java, slack, slack-api

I am trying to build interactive slack messages, but nothing happens when I click on the button in slack channel.

I used `slack-api-client` (java) to  build the interactive message. Message is being correctly posted to the channel but clicking on the button does not post the payload to the `request_url` configured. I see a triangle with mark of exclamation saying `This app returned an error. Please try again or contact the app's developer`. When I tried to check the network calls, I saw this error:

```
error_json: {"subtype":"missing_subtype","message":"hashed timestamp blocks.actions not ok: dispatch_failed"}
```

I am not sure what is missing here. I have configured my app and the request url ending with `/slack/events` is added at `interactivity and shortcut section`. The request url is public url and an be accessed directly. I am not sure why slack is not able to post the payload on click of the buttons.

Comment: You mention [tag:java] and the `slack-api-client` library. Can you please post a [example] with code and full error-output.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue, an have done some experiments.

It seems to be caused by the complexity of the message: If the message has too many blocks or the blocks are too complex it will send a wrong message timestamp to the slack server, which seems to cause this mysterious 403 error.

I reduced the number of blocks in the message and it works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

Interactive payloads are of different types and are required to handle accordingly:

https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#payloads

For Java based implementation, please refer here:

https://slack.dev/java-slack-sdk/guides/interactive-components

Comment: Only advising two link can be done as comment. We should first ask for code or clarify before answering.